# XMLDocument to xml file

Tags: c#, xml, .net-2.0

In my web services I am sending a XML document using this code,

```
      XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
      doc.LoadXml(myBigData.Serialize());
      return result = doc.DocumentElement;
```

Now In my c# console app I am calling this web method using,

```
      XmlElement returnedDataFromWebMethod = myWbSercvices.WebMethod();
```

Now how can I convert this XML element to a xml file e.g. in my C drive so i can see if xml document as document, instead of going through it using  `foreach(XMLNode)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
var node = doc.ImportNode(returnedDataFromWebMethod, true);
doc.AppendChild(node);
doc.Save("output.xml");
```

Answer (score 2):

create a new XmlDocument:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
```

call your web method and save it in an XmlNode

```
XmlNode returnedDataFromWebMethod = myWbSercvices.WebMethod();
```

append your element

```
doc.AppendChild(returnedDataFromWebMethod);
```

save the document

```
doc.Save("result.xml");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use XmlWriter and WriteTo method.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.writeto.aspx

Example:

```
XmlWriterSettings xmlSetings = new XmlWriterSettings();
xmlSetings.Indent = true;
xmlSetings.Encoding = Encoding.ASCII;

XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"C:\someFile.xml", xmlSetings);
returnedDataFromWebMethod.WriteTo(writer);
```

Comment: thanks but it;s giving me blank file, however when i try outerxml it does return few nodes

Comment: I don't know if that can be the source of empty-file problem, 'cause I don't have VS with me right now, but maybe you have not closed the writer: writer.WriteEndDocument();
writer.Flush();
writer.Close();